# Why $order->update_meta_data change my meta data (woocommerce)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I use `$order->update_meta_data` to `set` a payment `transaction id`. But next time when i use `get_meta`, i've `got a wrong data`.

For example:

- Set `1234567FFAB_123`
- Get `5421137FFAB_123`

I solved this by replacing the set function `$order->update_meta_data` to `update_post_meta($order->get_id(), $my_key, $my_value )`.

There was some questions like mine with gotted answers. But i didn't found it in 3-4 hours :D

This post to help to another guys like me and save their time:)

Comment: Call `$order->save()`  after `$order->update_meta_data()`